# How to see an AWS AppSync request/response $ctx object for an RDS data source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-appsync

I would like to see the generated $ctx object before and after it goes through the request and response vtl mappings. Is it possible? How to?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the appsync console and do not want to open cloud watch, you can use `$util.error("debug", "request", null, $util.toJson($ctx))`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, we can use the [appsync vtl utility helper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/utility-helpers-in-util.html).

Inside the request and response mappings, we can log the context using :
`$utils.log.info($utils.toJson($ctx))`